# IIS confuses me with app pool user

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

I am facing a weird problem with IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.
I run ASP MVC app employing Windows authentication. The AppPool user is specific user for this purpose. When I open the app with my browser from my computer, the app confuses me with app pool user. The thing is, that when I try to access it from my coworkers account, it gets the correct identity. I also logged in to another computer in my domain with my credentials which seems to solve the problem.

I tried the following:
- login via mobile phone (through Federation Gateway) - WORKS
- login from another tablet/PC within domain with my credentials - WORKS
- run IE on coworkers account with Run As and my credentials - WORKS
- IE on my computer, Chrome on my computer - I SEEM TO BE APP-POOL USER

Does anyone know where could the problem be?

**Edit:** it works perfectly with my production server, where it recognises me as who I really am. The "Advanced settings" of both App Pools are the same.

**Edit2:** I deleted a certificate named as server computer name from Other people Certificates folder (using certmgr.msc). After restart problem persist.

**Edit3:** I changed AppPool user to my private user credentials, but when I open the intranet application, the app still thinks I am the app pool user from before. So the problem seems to be on my computer somewhere.

Thank you

Comment: Do you read the user from `Controller.User`?

Comment: Yes
System.Security.Principal IPrincipal  Controller.User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was in **Credentials manager**.

> Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager

There was an entry which contained app pool username and password as credentials for my remote server. So the computer actually introduced itself as AppPool user.

I have no clue how it came here inside.

Answer (score 1):

Is your site allowing anonymous access as well as Windows? That could be one problem. (If anonymous is allowed, it won't ask for the Windows authentication)

Also check that the website is added to the Trusted Sites in Windows' Internet Options. Both IE and Chrome use that list to decide whether to automatically send your credentials to any website that asks.

Comment: My site is allowing ONLY Windows access, the same as on production server where everything woks fine. Also it would not work from other devices.
I checked Trusted sites on Internet Options, but it is all grayed out, so I can't even scroll to see the fill list.

Comment: You can also try adding it to the Intranet Sites list. That should have the same effect.

Comment: The application is listed in Intranet sites, but still no success.